# Migrating from 32 bit to 64

Tags: migration, runtime, 32bit-64bit, procedure

I am looking for some help with run-time errors in C++ application while converting to 64-bit. It worked fine in 32-bit for almost a decade. I compiled it using Visual Studio 2010 64-bit compiler. There are no compiler errors. The project compiles into a dll file, which is used by an executable (.exe) application also compiled in 64-bit. The problem I encountered is while passing parameters to Oracle PL/SQL procedure. After debugging the problem I learned that the value I am passing to Oracle has an extra null character at the end, and it runs fine without any problem when it comes to 32 bits version.

To get around that, I am using a CString variable in C++, which I am passing to the PL/SQL procedure. I removed the null character within the SQL code for now, but I understand that this is not a long-term solution.

What may be something that I am missing so I can get it to work in 64 bits as well without having to do any code changes? I don't want to do any code change because if I do I have do the changes in stored procedures and have to do that in each and every procedure (???). Definitely there has to be a better way to get this into working. If any one knows what I need to do or at least if you think I should try, please feel free to make me aware. The help will be greatly appreciated.